# Python Text-Based RPG - Weapon Selection

Tags: python, dictionary

I am working on an RPG where I want to find the best approach to capturing user input and create a class instance based on their selection. I start by presenting a list of weapons and their attributes. I've done this with a dictionary.

```
 melee_weapons = {'Broad Sword': {'damage':30, 'cost':25}, 
'Great Sword': {'damage':40, 'cost':45}, 'Spear': {'damage':20, 'cost':15}}
```

I then have this simple weapon class.

```
class Weapon:

    def __init__(self, name, damage, cost):
        self.name = name
        self.damage = damage
        self.cost = cost
```

Next, I have instances of all the weapons classes:

```
broad_sword = Weapon('Board Sword', 30, 25) 
great_sword = Weapon('Great Sword', 40, 45)
```

Finally, I have the function asking for input:

```
def weapon_selection():
    print(weapons + ranged_weapons)
    wp = int(input('What weapon would you like to pick? Enter the corresponding number'))
    if wp == 1:
        Character.weapon = broad_sword
    elif wp == 2:
        Character.weapon = great_sword
```

There aren't any inherent problems with this method, however, if there is a faster or more intuitive approach, I would be very appreciative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need for your dictionary

```
 melee_weapons = {'Broad Sword': {'damage':30, 'cost':25},
```

'Great Sword': {'damage':40, 'cost':45}, 'Spear': {'damage':20, 'cost':15}}

As you are manually supplying this information in the lines

```
broad_sword = Weapon('Board Sword', 30, 25) 
great_sword = Weapon('Great Sword', 40, 45)
```

If you would like to implement a dictionary then why not create your class instances like:

```
user_input = 'Great Sword' # or something similar
user_weapon = Weapon(weapon_list[user_input], weapon_list[user_input]['damage'], weapon_list[user_input]['cost'])
```

This way the user is supplying the key and you can automatically generate the weapon without having to create a weapon instance for every input to your dictionary by hand

Comment: @StephenStirling Glad to help :) I’d love if you could comment a link to the finished project so I could check it out!

Comment: I definitely will! Might take a little while to finish